# How to display Bean properties from ArrayList of Bean objects?

Tags: jsp, struts, jstl

I am using struts 1.3. In my action class I am accessing data from DB and setting the values in a Bean class objects (one object for each row). Finally I am adding the objects in an ArrayList object.
Now in my jsp I need to display this data(Bean property values).
I did this using scriptlets, Its working fine. But I want to use tags only(as recommended in standard way).
Could any one provide some idea how to use `<logic:iterate>` or `<nested:iterate>` whatever may work fine?

Here is my jsp code:

```
<% AppForm fm; %>
   <% Iterator itr; int i=0;
    ArrayList al=(ArrayList)request.getAttribute("data");
    System.out.println("ArrayList size is..."+al.size());
    if(al!=null)
    {
        for(itr=al.iterator(); itr.hasNext();i++)
        {
           fm=(AppForm)itr.next();
         %>
         <tr  id=i  onclick="toggle(this)" bgcolor="pink">
          <td align="center">
           <%= fm.getRegid() %>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
           <%= fm.getEid() %>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
           <%= fm.getFname() %>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
           <%= fm.getLname() %>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
           <%= fm.getDesignation() %>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
           <%= fm.getEmail() %>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
           <%= fm.getContact() %>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
           <%= fm.getAddress() %>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
           <%= fm.getQualification() %>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
           <%= fm.getJdate() %>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
           <%= fm.getReqdate() %>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
           <%= fm.getIpaddress() %>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
           <input type="radio" name="<%= fm.getEid() %>" value="approved" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.bgColor='DarkOliveGreen'"; />
          </td>
          <td align="center">
           <input type="radio" name="<%= fm.getEid() %>" value="rejected" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.bgColor='Orchid'"; />
          </td>

    </td>
         </tr> 
         <%
        }
    }
   %>
```

Comment: The recommended way is to use the JSTL (`<c:forEach>`) rather than the obsolete Struts logic tags. Read the documentation, and try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<c:forEach var="i" items ="${data}">
  <tr>
     <td>${i.eId}</td>
     <td>${i.lName}</td>
     ....................
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Hi Mr Dave,

Thank you for your reply. But I wish to use struts supplied tags. I think if it is possible with struts tags then no need of using JSTL tags. If you have any idea please let me know.

Comment: @ShaileshSaxena As JB said, when JSTL functionality overlaps with Struts 1 tags, JSTL should be preferred, as [mentioned in the S1 tag documentation](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/dev_logic.html).

Answer (score 1):

same version with struts tags

```
<logic:iterate id="item" name="data" indexId="idx">
  Row index: <bean:write name="idx"/>
  <bean:write name="item" property="eid"/>
  <bean:write name="item" property="fname"/>
</logic:iterate>
```